# Python's form data does not work as expected

Tags: python

I do have a website where I can see the form data in the Chrome Dev Tools. I would like to perform an HTTP request to it with this form data.

```
list: Random1
Random2
format: html
rnd: date.2022-07-07
```

The source of this form data is:

```
list=Random1%0D%0ARandom2&format=html&rnd=date.2022-07-07
```

The python code I do use for it looks like that:

```
form_data = {
    "list": ["Random1", "Random2"],
    "format": "plain",
    "rnd": "date.{0}".format(actual_date)
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work, and the validation says that the "list" should have at least two items inside. On the website the list is a textarea which allows to pass values that are separated by "enter" (new line) i.e.

```
Random1
Random2
...
```

How to covert such a textarea into a form data in python so I will be able to make a post request with it?

Comment: While they say two items which implies a list, it seems to be just one string where items are separated by CRLF. Try `"list": "Random1\r\nRandom2",`. If you want to keep a python list appy a join before sending it.

Comment: Your `list` form field isn't actually a list, it's just a string.  `"\r\n".join(theList)` would convert a list into the required format.